# How to setup a Cron to send newsletter?

Tags: cron, magento2.1.6

Please help me to setup a cron job to send newsletter in magento 2.1.6. Currently i'm not able to send newsletters to the subscribers. So i need to setup Cron job and check it out.

Thanks

Comment: did you setup the cronjob in your server?

Comment: No ,I'm new to this topic  how to set up it.Siteground is the host provider

Comment: https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/cpanel/cron_jobs.htm check link and try my ans in control panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your hosting provider uses cPanel, you should be able to use the following Cron Job:-

```
php /home/<CPANEL USERNAME>/public_html/bin/magento cron:run
php /home/<CPANEL USERNAME>/public_html/update/cron.php
php /home/<CPANEL USERNAME>/public_html/bin/magento setup:cron:run
```

Where `<CPANEL USERNAME>` will be the username for your cPanel account. This also assumes that your Magento store is in the "`public_html`" directory. If it is in other directories, do add them in after "`public_html`".

Some hosting providers may also use a different path to the PHP binary so you may need to double confirm with your provider on whether you can use just PHP or if you will need something else (like `/usr/bin/php`).

The first command (magento cron:run) will perform the reindex, send automated e-mails, generates the sitemap, etc.

Source : https://community.magento.com/t5/Hosting-Performance/Configuring-cron-job-for-siteground/td-p/37319d

Comment: In cron_schedule table i could found  newsletter_send_all  status as pending.

Comment: What is the schedule time it was set for news_letter. pending means it was schedule and it is in queue.